# SQL Server 2008 USE database with [] Delphi ADO

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

In SQL server 2008 Management studio I can do this

Use [C:\test\somedb...]

When I use Delphi 2009 with the same command, using ADO, the [] seems to be interpreted as a parameter and the command fails with parameter improperly defined error. There is no parameter - I just need to use the [] because of the \ in the file name. Double quotes don't work either in Delphi / ADO or Management Studio.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Delphi sees `:` and thinks it's a parameter, have you tried turning `ParamCheck` off?

Comment: I believe I did but as Ken White said the USE is not necessary so I removed it.

Comment: If I remove [] it fails because \ and : are not valid in an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ADO, you don't typically `USE` in the SQL. You specify the database and the other information (driver, etc.) in the `ConnectionString`. It works in SSMS because that's not using ADO; SSMS uses the SQL Server client directly (which has different requirements than ADO).

You can find connection string information for your specific SQL Server version [here](http://connectionstrings.com).

Comment: Hello - yes I know that. Some code I didn't write has this though and it caused a problem when the use statement was applied to a file based database where the file path contains a \ and was thus wrapped in [].